# Problem with importing the mplfinance module

Tags: python, import, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I am trying to get a candlestick graph for BTCUSDT using the `pip import pandas` module and the `pip install mpl_finance` module. I have successfully downloaded both modules and am now trying to import them into my project. All the websites I have come across tell me to import the mpl_finance module as: `import mplfinance as mpf` this however does not exist according to python so I was wondering if there is another way to import this or If they have perhaps updated it and it now requires different keywords? Essentially I need it to be able to run this function below:

```
mpf.plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably install wrong module, try:

```
pip install mplfinance
```

instead of

```
pip install mpl_finance
```

First command allowed me to do this command:

```
import mplfinance as mpf
```